# python Django how show category data on CART Page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Hi i am new i want to show after customer select a category product then related category other items show bellow on **CART** page. following are my model.

**Model.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

[Cart Page Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgNlE.png)

Comment: Anyone here help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well `category` isn't a related field.
But to show the value of a field with choices in the template you can use:

```
# assume the Item object is called item
{{ item.get_category_display }}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: hi thanks for your replay can you suggest me how i can get item on cart page then get all category from db?

Comment: but data are not show when i do it on cart page {{ item.get_category_display }}

Comment: There are so many things that could be going on.
Post the template code in your original question so people can see what you've got.